# How to enter a date into the attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

This may be something simple stupid but in QGIS 2.4 I have created a date column. How do I enter the date in correctly. Every time I type a date in, in whatever format it does not move that entered date into my attribute table. So I click on the table and open the form and try again but it never saves my entered data for the date.

Answer (score 10):

Not stupid at all buddy! Everyone has to learn sometime :)

You may have already tried the way I am going to describe as I use QGIS 2.2 instead of 2.4.

Open the attribute table, select *New column* and add the name and change the type:

[image: Add column]

The format I normally use is `YYYY-MM-DD` when typing in the Date column:

[image: Date]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does anyone know if there are plans for a 'date-picker' for QGIS when entering data such as this?

Comment: @mapBaker I guess milos.kroulik answered that one ;)

Answer (score 6):

In 2.4 there is even calendar widget ("date picker"). In the layers "Fields" tabs, select "Date/Time" widget for a date field and check "calendar popup" option in widget detail settings.

[image: QGIS Calendar Widget]

Comment: fantastic!!! great to see this!

Comment: Indeed, a very useful and easy-to-use widget.