# Between operator QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, filter, operator

I am using QGIS Essen version (2.14.1). I am trying to filter my data based on dates. I am wondering if the "between" operator exists like in SQL? 
I'm trying the following query but the results are wrong. Or is it the date format which is a problem?

```
(
(("all_ws_d_2"  <= '01-09-16') and  ("all_ws_d_3"   >=   '30-09-16'))
or (("all_ws_d_2"  >=  '01-09-16') and ("all_ws_d_3"  <= '30-09-16'))
or (("all_ws_d_2" <=  '01-09-16') and (("all_ws_d_3"   => '01-09-16') and ("all_ws_d_3"   <=  '30-09-16' )))
or (("all_ws_d_2" >= '01-09-16') and  (("all_ws_d_2"  <=   '30-09-16') and ("all_ws_d_3"  >=  '30-09-16')))
)
```

Comment: Your date format is probably wrong. See this post: [How to enter a date into the attribute table?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118543/how-to-enter-a-date-into-the-attribute-table). It should be "YYYY-MM-DD". By the way, I don't think there is a native between operator, but you can create a custom Python function.

Comment: @ArmoraerThanks it might be that, do you know how I can automatically change the format of my dates in QGIS, instead of doing a join from Excel?

Comment: There's a thread here with a couple of exampes of using the field calculator that I think does what you're after http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111209/date-format-conversion

Comment: Thanks! now i am getting the following error message, any ideas?

OGR [3] erreur 1: Type mismatch or improper type of arguments to <= operator.