# How to select data according to specific dates

Tags: qgis, expression, operator

I am using QGIS Essen version 2.14.1, and I am trying to select specific data according to dates in the field calculator:

I am using the following formula but the system is telling me: syntax error, unexpected LE

Here is my formula:

```
case when 
( "Copy of _4"  > 01/09/2016 and  "Copy of _5" < 18/09/2016)
 then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: What data types are your fields?

Comment: Related post (by same author): [Between operator QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193136/between-operator-qgis). Date format should be YYYY-MM-DD in string format (just tested on QGIS 2.16).

Comment: The date fields are strings actually. But it seems the query is wrong also?

Comment: If "Copy of _4" is of type `text`, then your error comes from the fact that you are trying to compare a text and a date, which is impossible. You'll have to use the `to_date` function to convert "Copy of _4" to date type.

Comment: Ok great thanks! And how would I put that in my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post my response to your comment as a real answer for readability purpose.

Your function should probably look like:

```
case when 
( to_date("Copy of _4") > '2016-09-01' and to_date("Copy of _5") < '2016-09-18')
 then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

This assumes that both "Copy of _4" and "Copy of _5" contain dates with the following format: YYYY-MM-DD (it probably won't work otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly improved version of ArMoraer's answer:

```
CASE WHEN
to_date(substr("Copy of _4", 7,5) + '-' + substr("Copy of _4", 4,2)  + '-' + substr("Copy of _4", 1,2)) > to_date('2016-09-01')
AND
to_date(substr("Copy of _5", 7,5) + '-' + substr("Copy of _5", 4,2)  + '-' + substr("Copy of _5", 1,2)) > to_date('2016-09-18')
THEN 'y' ELSE 'N' END
```

Be aware that this is rather messy and only works for the exact date format you're using here.